# PHP & Permissions

Tags: php, apache, permissions, file-permissions, chmod

I have an application that I am transferring to a new server. In doing so the upload feature for customers accounts stopped working because the owner of the folders was 'ftp' and not 'apache' I solved it by renaming the folder and then using a directory copy function that I copied and pasted from somewhere in to a new folder with the correct name and it was all cool after that.

My question is this, can php change the ownership of a folder or files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, php can change ownership of a file. Use [`chown($file, $user)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php). You could write a simple recursive script to change owner for each file using chown.

Comment: ahh I thought chown just told you the owner. I don't know how I managed to come to that conclusion. Thank you.

Comment: Of course, it's making me wait at the moment. Good job you mentioned it though because it's my first ever question I probably would have forgot.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, **as far as the user under which it runs has the permissions to do that.**

You could use the [chown](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php) function or wrap the shell command in an exec call to do it recursively with no need to program that as in

```
exec('chown -R user <your-dir>');
```

Comment: That is probably the best way but I was on a new server; I was still working out where everything was.